# Spring WebClient - How to handle the errors on the body Rest

Tags: java, json, error-handling, spring-webclient

I'm a newbie with Spring Boot, and I need your help.

I make a GET request with WebClient, and I receive a JSON body as below:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "error": [],
    "payload": {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe"
...
    }
}
```

So I have a DTO class in which mapping the response. Something like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseAccountDTO {
    
    private String status;
    private List<ErrorDTO> errors;
    private User payload;

}
```

I do it whit this method:

```
public ResponseUserDTO retrieveUserById(String userId) {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri(GET_USER_BY_ID_V4, accountId)
        .header("Auth-Schema", AUTH_SCHEMA)
        .header("apikey", API_KEY)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
            System.out.println("4xx error");
            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("4xx"));
        })
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> {
            System.out.println("5xx error");
            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("5xx"));
        })
        .bodyToMono(ResponseDTO.class)
        .block();
}
```

Finally, I test it with this method:

```
UserRestClient userRestClient = new UserRestClient(webClient);

@Test
void retrieveUser() {
    ResponseDTO response = userRestClient.retrieveUserById("123");
    UserDTO user = response.getPayload();
    System.out.println("user surname: " + user.surname);
    assertEquals("Doe", user.getSurname());
}
```

All fine until the response has KO Status. If something goes wrong (i.e., BAD REQUEST), I receive the same body JSON structure, as below:

```
{
    "status": "KO",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "ER000",
            "description": "Wrong ID parameter",
            "params": ""
        }
    ],
    "payload": {}
}
```

Is there a way to map also with KO Status the JSON body on my DTO class?
I want to return the error description on my retrieveUser() method.

Update:
I add my ErrorDTO class as suggest by Seelenvirtuose

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDTO {
    
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private String params;

}
```

Comment: Your DTO class seem to be able to hold the whole JSON structure (if `ErrorDTO` is well designed). What problems do you have with it?

Comment: Hi Seelen, I just added my class ErrorDTO code. The problem is that when I receive the error it goes here `.onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {`

Comment: I really do not understand. What problem do you have with this code? Please add any error or whatever problem description might be appropriate to your question. If you do not want to react on an error status, then simply do not call the `onStatus` method.

Comment: If I do not call the onStatus an error is thrown and the end of the method is never reached so I do not have data in my ErrorDTO

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: `Response 400 BAD_REQUEST`

Answer (score 1):

I myself ran into this issue and had to convert the json error response to an ErrorDTO object.

Hope the below code helps you for what you are looking for.

The below code can be applied to any Status code (e.g. 4xx, 5xx and even for 2xx as well but you won't need it for 2xx)

```
.onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, error -> error
  .bodyToMono(Map.class)
  .flatMap(body -> {      
     try {
         var message = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(body);
         ErrorDTO errorResponse = objectMapper.readValue(message, ErrorDTO.class);
         return Mono.error(new ServiceException(error.statusCode().value(), "My custom error message",                                                         errorResponse));
     } catch (JsonProcessingException jsonProcessingException) {
         return Mono.error(new ServiceException("Cannot parse the error response"));
     }
  })
)
```